# HTML/CSS responsiveness issues on iOS devices

Tags: css, ios, frontend, media-queries, responsiveness

I am having an issue with HTML/CSS web page style. Namely, responsiveness adjustments are not working properly on exclusively iOS devices.To be precise, so-called "blog cards" are not showing properly as you can see on the link below:

https://bloggy.glitch.me/

Source Code is here:

https://github.com/00009115/WebTech.CW2.00009115

CSS may seem not clean since I am adjusting older project of mine to a new Node.js project. However, I had the same issues with older one as well.

I repeat, the issues is only with iOS devices. Screenshot is attached below:

[Screenshot from an iOS device showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO53E.jpg)

I would really appreciate if someone can help me to fix this issue. And please, don't pay attention to other responsiveness issues which I will fix soon.

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: can you link the css file used for that particular view?

Comment: https://github.com/00009115/WebTech.CW2.00009115/blob/master/public/styles/main.css starting from line 443 and the class of card is .blog-card

Comment: Please put enough code in the actual question so that we can see the problem for ourselves - see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for info on how to do this. Some of us are keen to help but not to have to go through hundreds of lines of code on an external site. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. This is my first-question. Next time I will consider this

Answer (score 0):

You can write separate media queries for iPhone devices, the thing is iPhone mobile resolution bit differs from android and standard devices. ex: iPhone 5 and se aspect ratios.

For further details refer to this:
[CSS media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

or use the Bootstrap CSS framework, hope this helps with your problem.

Comment: This didn't help. I could solve the issue by giving fit-content to the card height. Thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

In the file https://github.com/00009115/WebTech.CW2.00009115/blob/master/public/styles/main.css
in the code block at line 443
you can notice

```
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
-webkit-box-align: center;
```

this is known as box-flex and they have very poor cross-browser compatibility, So you shouldn't be using this. try using flex box or grid.
to read more about this problem and browser compatibility for this particular property you can refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-flex

In fact, you shouldn't use something like this in production at least.
I hope that answers your problem.

Happy learning!

Comment: Actually, I am using flex-box and a third-party software compiled my CSS to make it more cross-browser. I could solve the issue by giving fit-content to the card height. Thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by giving more responsive value to the height of the card. Namely:

```
height: fit-content;
```